# Return False From Clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval, tampermonkey

im Trying to Make the Click dont do the Work if there is a word (Hello) on the Website 
But if there isn't a word Hello then will Keep Click on the iD(safe)

```
if ((document.body.innerText).indexOf('Hello') == 1)

{
    return false;


    $('#safe').trigger('click');


}
```

Comment: No clue what that code is trying to do. The code after the return false is not going to run.

Comment: Are you trying to disable the button? Hide the button? Not execute a function (the click)? 

You are not being clear what you need.

Comment: Sorry guy's im Trying to Click at a button but When a hello text appears the Click will Stop

Comment: show more of the function

Comment: im trying to Click on ElementbyId safe but in condition if a text appears(Hello) the Click wont do the job

Comment: If you could show the innerText html portion you would people understand the context. Provide an example of the input you are checking.

Comment: if ((document.body.innerText).indexOf('Hello') > -1)
{
    return false;
} else {
    $('#safe').trigger('click');
}

Comment: thx its Work Ebik Ghazarian <3 <3

Comment: @CHEATSupport Yw :) but it's Evik haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<html>
  <p>Hello</p> <!-- remove this line to see what if no Hello on page -->

  <button type='button' id='safe' onclick="isHelloThere()">click me</button>

  <script type='text/javascript'>
    function isHelloThere() {
      if ((document.body.innerText).indexOf('Hello') > -1) {
        // do nothing
      } else {
        alert('I do not see a Hello word on the page.')
      }
    }
  </script>
</html>
```

You probably need to update your questions with more details. Anyway, according to your comments, I guess this is what you need.

You can create a click function then determine if there is Hello on the page in your click function. https://jsfiddle.net/jialinzou/cztmusLr/28/